# Axios response data is not saved with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

While trying to fetch data from my express backend and MySQL database, with my react frontend using axios, it fails to set the fetched data using useState

my frontend function looks like this

```
const searchUser = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/searchUser", {
      username: username,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data) {
        setResult(response.data);
      }
    });
  };
```

and my backend function looks like this

```
const searchUser = (req, res) => {
  const keyword = req.body.username;
  db.query(
    "SELECT id,username FROM users WHERE username like ?",
    "%" + keyword + "%",
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        res.json({ result });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I tried many methods while saving the data with the useState hook, I appreciate any help

Comment: What does "fails to set" mean?

Comment: fails to save the response to a const with useState hook

Comment: Did you try console.logging the response? Do you get the correct response in the front end?

Comment: @vanpersie22 What does "fail to save" mean? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking future questions, to help make the questions appropriate for Stackoverflow and to help people answer your questions. It helps to be as specific as possible about your question, specifically what you expect to happen, and what isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

While using Promises and then instead of async / await make sure to catch the errors if your fetch fails.

Unless you share with us the whole component that contains the `searchUser` function and how you defined the state i cannot pin point you on the error.

What i suggest you to do is adding a catch to your fetch by doing the following:

```
const searchUser = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/searchUser", {
      username: username,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data) {
        setResult(response.data);
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };
```

If any abnormalities has happened in your request the catch will tell you! Don't underestimate it's power.

Another path you can look into is console logging your output in front end `searchUser` function just before setting it in the state.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem, just by replacing res.json({ result }); to res.json(result);  in the last line in my backend function